# Is this valid CSV escaping? Lumenworks throws an exception but other parsers seem to work

Tags: csv, lumenworks

I'm updating a legacy system that parses CSVs. I decided to use the [LumenWorks](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LumenWorks.Framework.IO/)  csv library. It struggles on records like this:

```
"Cats","123","A","B","Mittens","1","2","3","1950",""PROBLEM IS HERE"","Some street","Fishtown","","AB13DF","United Kingdom","","","","","","","United Kingdom","Fiddles"
```

As far as I can tell this should be escaped as `"""PROBLEM IS HERE"""`. Can anyone confirm? If it's valid then I need to find a fix, but if it's not I can inform the client that the CSV they provided isn't formed correctly.

Also if there's a way around this using LumenWorks (a non-hack way ideally) that will prevent it throwing an exception, that'd be good to know. Thanks!

I should add that LumenWorks gives me this: `LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv.MalformedCsvException: The CSV appears to be corrupt near record ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the Lumenworks site doesn't specify that it's compliant with [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), the current expected escaping is specified as:

> 7. If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
> appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
> another double quote.  For example:
>
> ```
> "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
> ```

Therefore, to include the string `"PROBLEM IS HERE"`, you need to double the quotes, producing `""PROBLEM IS HERE""`, then enclose it in double quotes, producing `"""PROBLEM IS HERE"""`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. Link to the spec is appreciated, I can confidently confront the client now and tell them it's not me :)

Comment: Good luck!  You can safely say that simple doubled quotes (not tripled) are broken in this situation.  Sometimes people also try to pass off CSVs with backslashes as the escape character, which is a violation of the RFC but still the expected behavior in some places.